# In MS Access, how do I summarise data based on data within the same query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access that looks similar to the table below. I am trying to create a query that will roll up the Overheads into the Tasks, such that it looks like the second table below.

```
Quote       Task        Cost    Total USD
=========   ==========  ====    =========
Quote-001   Task001      1.5          1.5
Quote-001   Task002      1.4          1.4
Quote-001   Task003      1.3          1.3
Quote-001   Task004      1.2          1.2
Quote-001   Overhead-A    10           10
Quote-001   Overhead-B     5            5
Quote-001   Overhead-B     2            2
-----------------------------------------
                       Total         22.4
```

The following table has the sum of the overheads (10+5+2) = 17, divided across the four tasks (4.25 added to each Task amount).

```
Quote       Task        Cost    Total USD
=========   ==========  ====    =========
Quote-001   Task001     5.75         5.75
Quote-001   Task002     5.65         5.65
Quote-001   Task003     5.55         5.55
Quote-001   Task004     5.45         5.45
-----------------------------------------
                       Total         22.4
```

Is this even possible using an Access query?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Consider derived tables of aggregate queries that sum the *Overhead* Costs and counts the *Task* items, each joined by *Quote*. Then use the aggregates in adjusting the *Cost* and *Total* fields.

```
SELECT t1.Quote, t1.Task,
       t1.Cost + (t2.OverheadCost/t3.TaskCount) As NewCost, 
       t1.[Total USD] + (t2.OverheadCost/t3.TaskCount) As NewTotal
FROM (Overheads As t1

INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Overheads.Quote, Sum(Overheads.Cost) As OverheadCost
      FROM Overheads
      WHERE Overheads.Task ALIKE '%Overhead%'
      GROUP BY Overheads.Quote) As t2
ON t1.Quote = t2.Quote)

INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Overheads.Quote, Count(*) As TaskCount
      FROM Overheads
      WHERE Overheads.Task ALIKE '%Task%'
      GROUP BY Overheads.Quote) As t3
ON t1.Quote = t3.Quote

WHERE t1.Task ALIKE '%Task%';

-- Quote           Task  NewCost   NewTotal
-- Quote-001    Task001     5.75       5.75
-- Quote-001    Task002     5.65       5.65
-- Quote-001    Task003     5.55       5.55
-- Quote-001    Task004     5.45       5.45
```

Alternatively, in MS Access, you can save both aggregate queries as stored queries and reference them in final query.

```
SELECT t1.Quote, t1.Task,
       t1.Cost + (t2.OverheadCost/t3.TaskCount) As NewCost, 
       t1.[Total USD] + (t2.OverheadCost/t3.TaskCount) As NewTotal
FROM (Overheads As t1    
INNER JOIN qrySumOverHeadCost As t2 ON t1.Quote = t2.Quote)    
INNER JOIN qryCountTaskItems As t3 ON t1.Quote = t3.Quote    
WHERE t1.Task ALIKE '%Task%';
```

Answer (score 0):

JET syntax is always an adventure. If it were SQL Server, it would be possible to store the task count and the overhead totals in declared variables, but here we need to store them in subqueries. The other option is to use multiple queries in a VBA module, which would be easier to read and have better performance over a large set.

```
SELECT a.Quote, 
  a.Task, 
  ROUND(a.Cost + OverTot.Cost / aCount.Count,2) AS [Count],
  ROUND(a.Total_USD + OverTot.Total_USD / aCount.Count,2) AS [Total_USD]
FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT t.Quote, 
        t.Task, 
        SUM(t.Cost) AS [Cost], 
        SUM(t.Total_USD) AS [Total_USD]
      FROM Table1 t
      WHERE LEFT(t.Task,8) <> "OverHead"
      GROUP BY t.Quote, 
        t.Task
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  t.Quote, 
        SUM(t.Cost) AS [Cost], 
        SUM(t.Total_USD) AS [Total_USD]
      FROM Table1 t
      WHERE LEFT(t.Task,8) = "OverHead"
      GROUP BY t.Quote, 
        LEFT(t.Task,8)
    ) OverTot ON a.Quote = OverTot.Quote
  )
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT t.Quote, 
      COUNT(t.Task) AS [Count]
    FROM Table1 t
    WHERE LEFT(t.Task,8) <> "OverHead"
    GROUP BY t.Quote
  ) aCount ON a.Quote = aCount.Quote
```